# can floating point multiplication throw an exception in C++?

Tags: c++, noexcept

Is this possible? I don't think it is, but I don't know if this is something the standard would say, or if it's implementation defined? I'm asking because I'm wondering whether it's safe or worth it to mark a constexpr function like this noexcept

EX:

```
constexpr double to_meters(double y) noexcept? {
  return y * 10;
}
constexpr double x = to_meters(y); // Clang-Tidy warns about possible exception without noexcept
```

Comment: Possibly relevant http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/math_errhandling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The language definition doesn't give you any guarantees here, but since virtually every implementation (that is, there are none I know of that don't) implements IEEE-754 math, which does not throw exceptions, it's not something I'd worry about. And more generally, a floating-point math package that throws exceptions would have had to be written with C++ in mind; that's highly unlikely.

However, you may well get messages when a floating-point error occurs that refer to a "floating-point exception"; that's a **floating-point** exception, not a **C++** exception, and it has nothing to do with C++ exceptions. It's a runtime error, with a peculiar name.

Answer (score 5):

No, float point multiplication will normally not throw a C++ exception.

But think about this: How can clang-tidy possibly know whether `to_meter` will throw an exception? In C++ every function can throw an exception unless it is explicitly declared not to throw.

So clang-tidy has two options: It could do expensive (possibly inconclusive) control flow analysis or it can simply rely on you correctly declaring `nothrow`, [which it does](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang-tools-extra/blob/407b4a570b2ab6776605f1527715afc570590232/clang-tidy/cert/StaticObjectExceptionCheck.cpp#L31):

```
  Finder->addMatcher(
      varDecl(anyOf(hasThreadStorageDuration(), hasStaticStorageDuration()),
              unless(hasAncestor(functionDecl())),
              anyOf(hasDescendant(cxxConstructExpr(hasDeclaration(
                        cxxConstructorDecl(unless(isNoThrow())).bind("func")))),
                                         //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                    hasDescendant(cxxNewExpr(hasDeclaration(
                        functionDecl(unless(isNoThrow())).bind("func")))),
                                    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                    hasDescendant(callExpr(hasDeclaration(
                        functionDecl(unless(isNoThrow())).bind("func"))))))
          .bind("var"),
      this);
```

Comment: From the question, I think OP is expecting ctidy to be able to deduce whether or not functions in the same file throw without a hint.

Answer (score 2):

Arithmetic cannot throw an exception in C++.  With the usual caveat that if code causes undefined behaviour then anything can happen. So you can mark your function as `noexcept`.

Floating point multiplication may cause undefined behaviour if the result would be out of range.

The "floating point exceptions" are flags that don't interrupt your program: you must test for them using `std::fetestexcept` and then you can decide what to do. Several of the [FE_ flags listed here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/FE_exceptions) may be raised by floating point multiplication.